# iOS 9 compatible version of NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:repeats:block:?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using the following code in iOS 10 but when I run it in iOS 9 it crashes.  I don't think [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:repeats:block:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimer/2091888-timerwithtimeinterval?language=objc) supports iOS 9.  How can I implement a timer that will work in iOS 8 - 10?

```
static NSTimer* timer = nil;

- (void)documentInteractionControllerWillBeginPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 repeats:YES block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    }];
}

-(void)documentInteractionControllerDidEndPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    [timer invalidate];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: What does the crash log say. FYI NSTimer has been around forever.

Comment: Another reason for using Swift. It would have refused to compile, and thus would have prevented the crash. That's because Swift _knows_ that this method isn't supported on iOS 9. I'm surprised to hear that Objective-C hasn't caught up. You didn't even get a warning? Amazing.

Answer (score 5):

You appear to be using a function introduced in iOS10. Further down the page you linked is a function that was in iOS 2.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimer/1408356-timerwithtimeinterval?language=objc

Use that instead.

Answer (score 3):

This fixed it:

```
static NSTimer* timer = nil;

- (void)documentInteractionControllerWillBeginPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(hideStatusBar) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)hideStatusBar
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}

-(void)documentInteractionControllerDidEndPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    [timer invalidate];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}
```